# How to use System.Posix.DynamicLinker on Haskell shared libraries

Tags: haskell, dynamic-linking

Say I have a compiled shared Haskell library (Linux). Can I somehow use System.Posix.DynamicLinker (dlopen and dlsym) on it to get actually callable Haskell functions? If so, what string to pass to dlsym (I think Haskell function names are somehow mangled) and how can the returned FunPtr be converted to a Haskell function? I think at least the Haskell runtime has to do something like that.

Has somebody done something like this?

Comment: You need to 'foreign export' the function you want to call.

Comment: Read the FFI spec, it explains a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want    http://hackage.haskell.org/package/plugins

Comment: Well, sort of. It currently doesn't compile on my machine (fails with: src/System/Plugins/Load.hs:87:35:
    Module `GHC' does not export `defaultCallbacks' and also it seems you need the object file, the .hi file and a package.conf. While this would be generally ok (if I would get it to compile), I would be curious to know the low level stuff also.